# Second item in Onsen UI carousel does not show after swiping

Tags: carousel, onsen-ui

I am trying to implement a feature to delete a list item on swipe. I am using a carousel for each item in my list. The issue is that the second `carousel-item` is not showing: it only leaves a blank space.

Here is my carousel:

```
<ons-list id ="list" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
            <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" onclick="menu.setMainPage('default.html', {closeMenu: true, callback: function(){getPageContent(0);}});" style="overflow: hidden;position: relative;width: 100%;">

               <ons-carousel class = "list__item_active;" style="height: 100%;position: absolute;right: 0;top: 0;" swipeable auto-scroll>
                <ons-carousel-item >

                  Presentation 1 (sqlite)
                <ons-carousel-item>
                <ons-carousel-item>

                  DELETE
                <ons-carousel-item>
               <ons-carousel>
            </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
```

Comment: Something like this? http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/ByMmwE

Comment: thank you for ur comment.I already saw some working examples, i just wanted to know what's wrong with my code. I am missing something and i can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The carousel did have more than 2 items, may be an infinity of items.
the problem was about tags that are not closed.

```
<ons-list id ="list" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
            <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" onclick="menu.setMainPage('default.html', {closeMenu: true, callback: function(){getPageContent(0);}});" style="overflow: hidden;position: relative;width: 100%;">

               <ons-carousel class = "list__item_active;" style="height: 100%;position: absolute;right: 0;top: 0;" swipeable auto-scroll>
                <ons-carousel-item >

                  Presentation 1 (sqlite)
                </ons-carousel-item>
                <ons-carousel-item>

                  DELETE
                </ons-carousel-item>
               </ons-carousel>
            </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```